# Error passing an array with MPI_Send and MPI_Recv

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying yo pass and receive an array of doubles wicth `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` but it's not working

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define N 5
#define ITERS 10
#define ARRAY_SIZE (N+2) * (N+2)
// N and ITERS might be input arguments

double **A;

void initialize (double **A)
{
  int i,j;

   for(i =0; i < N+2 ; i++){
     for(j =0; j < N+2 ; j++){
      if(i== 0 || j == 0 || i == (N+1) || j == (N +1) )
        A[i][j] = 0.0;
      else
        A[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;
     }
   }
}
void showArray(double **A){
  int i,j;
  printf("\n");
  for(i =0 ; i < N+2 ; i++){
    for(j =0; j < N+2 ; j++){
      printf("%f, ",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void stencil(double **A){
  int i,j;
  printf("\n");
  for(i =1 ; i <= N ; i++){
    for(j =1; j <=N ; j++){
      A[i][j] = 0.3 *( A[i][j] + A[i-1][j] + A[i+1][j] + A[i][j-1] + A[i][j+1]);
    }
  }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

  int MyProc, size,tag=1;
  char msg='A', msg_recpt;
  MPI_Status status;
  double **received_array;

  //showArray(A);
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &MyProc);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

  printf("Process # %d started \n", MyProc);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  //allocating received_array
  received_array = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double *));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<N+2; i++) {
    received_array[i] = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double));
  }

  if(MyProc == 0){
    A = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double *));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<N+2; i++) {
      A[i] = malloc((N+2) * sizeof(double));
    }
    initialize(A);
    stencil(A);
    showArray(A);
    //printf("sizeof: %d\n",sizeof(A)/sizeof(double));

    MPI_Send(A, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, MyProc +1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("Proc #%d enviando a #%d\n",MyProc,MyProc+1 );
  }

  if(MyProc > 0 && MyProc < size -1){
    MPI_Recv(received_array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, MyProc- 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    printf("Proc #%d recibe de Proc #%d\n",MyProc,MyProc- 1 );
    //stencil(A);
    printf("Proc #%d enviando a #%d\n",MyProc,MyProc+1 );
    MPI_Send(received_array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, MyProc +1,tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }

  if(MyProc == size -1 ){
    MPI_Recv(received_array, ARRAY_SIZE, MPI_DOUBLE, MyProc- 1, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    printf("Proc #%d recibe de Proc #%d\n",MyProc,MyProc- 1 );
    //stencil(A);
  }

  printf("Finishing proc %d\n", MyProc);
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();

}
```

I get this error

```
[compute-0-4.local:30784] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[compute-0-4.local:30784] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[compute-0-4.local:30784] *** MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer
[compute-0-4.local:30784] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
[compute-0-4.local][[28950,1],0][btl_tcp_frag.c:215:mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv] mca_btl_tcp_frag_recv: readv failed: Connection reset by peer (104)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 1 with PID 30784 on
node compute-0-4.local exiting improperly. There are two reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.

2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[compute-0-4.local:30782] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[compute-0-4.local:30782] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Now allocating memory for `received_array` I get this error message:

```
[compute-0-0:18176] *** Process received signal ***
[compute-0-0:18177] *** Process received signal ***
[compute-0-0:18177] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[compute-0-0:18177] Signal code:  (128)
[compute-0-0:18177] Failing at address: (nil)
[compute-0-0:18176] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[compute-0-0:18176] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[compute-0-0:18176] Failing at address: 0x10
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x326fa0f500]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 1] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_memory_ptmalloc2_int_malloc+0xae) [0x2b22bf88211e]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 2] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_memory_ptmalloc2_malloc+0x57) [0x2b22bf883b87]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 3] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(+0x2258f7) [0x2b22bf88b8f7]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 4] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(mca_base_param_reg_int_name+0x3f) [0x2b22bf88bd9f]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 5] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(ompi_mpi_finalize+0x126) [0x2b22bf6f5fb6]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 6] ./ej7(main+0x2d2) [0x4010e8]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 7] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x326f21ecdd]
[compute-0-0:18176] [ 8] ./ej7() [0x400ac9]
[compute-0-0:18176] *** End of error message ***
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0() [0x326fa0f500]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 1] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_memory_ptmalloc2_int_malloc+0xae) [0x2b52f96ff11e]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 2] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(opal_memory_ptmalloc2_malloc+0x57) [0x2b52f9700b87]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 3] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(+0x2258f7) [0x2b52f97088f7]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 4] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(mca_base_param_reg_int_name+0x3f) [0x2b52f9708d9f]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 5] /opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.1(ompi_mpi_finalize+0x126) [0x2b52f9572fb6]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 6] ./ej7(main+0x2d2) [0x4010e8]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 7] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x326f21ecdd]
[compute-0-0:18177] [ 8] ./ej7() [0x400ac9]
[compute-0-0:18177] *** End of error message ***
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 1 with PID 18176 on node compute-0-0.local exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Answer (score 1):

Allocate `received_array` in a similar way as you allocated `A`.

MPI doesn't allocate memory, even if you pass arrays around.

Then your issue after edit is that your are transferring a square matrix that was allocated as a pointer of pointer with one MPI send instead of using `N+2` calls, one for each row. And this doesn't work, because what MPI_Send/MPI_Recv do is sending `ARRAY_SIZE` contiguous elements...

In HPC, we use 1D arrays, of `ARRAY_SIZE` directly, and then use macros (for instance) to get the 2D accesses, because it's fast, cache-friendly, and doesn't require `N+2` calls (which is bad for latency) instead of just one.

Comment: I've allocated `received_array` and I get another error message ,it's edited on the original post

Comment: Edited the post, you can't send a pointer of arrays with just one call.